# SQL - Repeating same query block

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
select * from ( select * from y where x="t") where z rlike "(.*)query1"
union
select * from ( select * from y where x="t") where z rlike "(.*)query2"
```

As you can see above, parenthesis contain the same query which typically 
returns multi-row results. Is there any way to optimize it by only querying once for the select statement inside the parenthesis and using the result over and over again?

PS: I want to get the results in an ordered manner, so the results of the first unioned query must stay at top.

Comment: What do you mean by `ordered manner`? you must have cases when z ends with `query1` first?

Comment: @Benoit assume that `(query1) union (query2);` query1 returns row1 and, query2 returns row0. I want this order: row1,row0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things here:

- First, avoid `UNION` if you can use `UNION ALL`. Plain `union`s involve removal of duplicates and thus take more time.
- When you can factor a query, do it. Here you have union of exact queries except for one criterion, then you can use `OR`.
- `select * from (select * ...` is redundancy and can be avoided.

Which gives:

```
SELECT *
  FROM y
 WHERE x = 't'
   AND ( z RLIKE '(.*)query1'
        OR
         z RLIKE '(.*)query2'
       )
```

As said in a comment by melpomene (thanks!) you can even factor at the regex level:
 `WHERE z RLIKE '(.*)query1|(.*)query2'`

If there are duplicates in `y` and you don't want them, since `UNION` discarded them, you can introduce `DISTINCT` but avoid if it is not necessary.

If you want an order, never rely on the DBMS. Use `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN z RLIKE '(.*)query1' THEN 1
              WHEN z RLIKE '(.*)query2' THEN 2
              ELSE 3 -- given the WHERE clause, should never happen
         END
```

Comment: If that's a regex, you could even do `z RLIKE '(.*)query1|(.*)query2'`.

Comment: It's maybe worth pointing out that there are cases where UNIONs result in better query plans than ORs.  But it's probably better to start with the OR and only switch to UNION if there is a very bad plan being selected.

Comment: union gives the results in an ordered manner(results of the first unioned querry at the top). Does OR provide the same behavior?

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı: if you had ordered results, it is by *chance*. You NEVER have a guarantee on the order of the results with your DBMS *unless* you use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Benoit I don't say it is ordered to some column(I know ORDER BY), I mean it is ordered such that first unioned query resulted rows stay at top of the overall result.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı, if you had results of the first query first, then you were just lucky. The DBMS is free to output rows in any order if you don't specify an ORDER BY, and only ORDER BY can control that order for sure. (with Oracle, there is also ORDER SIBLINGS and CONNECT BY).

Comment: @Is there anyway to impose the ordering as I want?

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı, yes, see the end of the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20101/discussion-between-benoit-and-seckin-savasci)